# Chromium Ubuntu 13.10 - No webapp setup prompt no webapp icon

Tags: icons, chromium, webapps, prompt

I have a completely fresh install for Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit on *Dell Latitude E6510*. (I also had the same problem on the same laptop using 13.10 32-bit). I use Chromium as my web browser.

Webapps are not working: Chromium Ubuntu 13.10 - No webapp setup prompt &  webapp icons show up as chromium icon.

Already done are:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-chromium-extension  

sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-*
```

Also in *dconf* `/com/canonical/unity/webapps`

```
allowed-domains []  
dontask-domains []  
index-update-time 43200  
integration-allowed ticked  
preauthorized-domains ['amazon.ca', 'amazon.cn', 'amazon.com', 'amazon.co.uk', 'amazon.de', 'amazon.es', 'amazon.fr', 'amazon.it', 'www.amazon.ca', 'www.amazon.cn', 'www.amazon.com', 'www.amazon.co.uk', 'www.amazon.de', 'www.amazon.es', 'www.amazon.fr', 'www.amazon.it', 'one.ubuntu.com']
```

Online account enaled: Google, Facebook.

There are two issues here:

(1) No webapp setup prompts: Case: Upon opening of Gmail, LinkedIn, Launchpad, etc., I expected to be prompted to enable the webapp but this did not happen.

(2) Webapp icons do not work. Case: Gmail does work. It was already there. No prompts or install procedures. However, whilst its icon is separate on the launcher, it is not a Gmail icon but a chromium icon.

How can I fix these issues ?

Comment: I'm having same problem. I am not getting prompted either and I'm on a fresh install. Haven't tried Firefox, but Chromium seems to not work with this at all despite having the extension installed.